# Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\x96" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 error while writing to a file in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, utf-8

I am having a function which writes the filenames to a file in ruby.
but I am getting this error:

```
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\x96" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
```

to overcome this is used:

```
file = File.open("names", "w")
file.puts(filename.force_encoding("utf-8"))
```

doing this solved this problem, but when I am again reading through the file and try to open files whose `names` are stored in names file.
I am getting an error saying `CANNNOT STAT: NO SUCH FILE OR FOLDER EXISTS`.

any suggestions are welcome..!!

Comment: Operating system? Example of file name that fails?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 14.04 
filename : "Volunteer Log \x96 in Page.docx"

Comment: Uhkhm. Please post the output of `ls` being executed in this directory.

Comment: Volunteer Log ? in Page.docx

Comment: Is this a file from a Windows system? In [CP-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), `\x96` would be a `–`

Comment: no this is log file from wordpress, its name is in ASCII-8bit.

Comment: @ritzz.soni ASCII does not define `\x96`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I will try to suggest.

It sounds like you have received this file from a workstation, running Windows. It looks like this file’s original name is

```
Volunteer Log – in Page.docx
```

That said, is was stored using `Encoding::CP1252`. OK, you are to handle `CP1252` in a proper way:

```
file = File.open 'names', 'w'
file.puts filename.force_encoding(Encoding::CP1252).encode(Encoding::UTF_8)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have checked the file encoding and its ASCII-8BIT,
i tried with file = File.open 'names', 'w'
file.puts filename.force_encoding(Encoding::ASCII_8BIT).encode(Encoding::UTF_8)
but it gives error
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\x96" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8

Comment: Just try the code above. I am pretty sure it would do the trick.

Comment: Sorry didnt worked,
got 
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory